# Silverlight XAML databinding to a field

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml, ria

in the following code,

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="False" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my:V_FinanceCalculatorDefaultValues, CreateList=true}" Height="0" LoadedData="v_FinanceCalculatorDefaultValuesDomainDataSource_LoadedData" Name="v_FinanceCalculatorDefaultValuesDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetV_FinanceCalculatorDefaultValuesQuery" Width="0">
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                <my:DomainServiceFinanceCalculatorDefaultValues />
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
                <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="modelId" Value="{Binding ElementName=modelIdTextBox, Path=Text}" />
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

how do I set the value of the parameter to a field in the associated C# class?

```
public int SelectedModelUcConfigurator;
```

I tried something like this

```
 <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="modelId" Value="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=SelectedModelUcConfigurator}" />
```

I realize this is something simple, but I'm new to WPF ... :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try make a readonly property for SelectedModelUcConfigurator and bind to the property.

```
private int _selectedModelUcConfigurator; 

public int SelectedModelUcConfigurator
{ 
get { return _selectedModelUcConfigurator; } 
}
```

Comment: any chance you could elaborate a little? Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer.

It might not make a difference, I dont know if WPF can bind towards a variable. But even if it doesn't help it's best practise to bind towards a property instead. :)